# Why is it when I use SpecialCharacters#addItems(), I am getting unintended special characters?

Tags: ckeditor5

I am making a simple category of special characters that I intend to only have 2 characters: ° (degree) and ± (plus minus).

I am aware that I can include the SpecialCharactersMathematical plugin, which includes those two symbols, but it also includes a lot more symbols I do not want. I just want a simple special character menu with just those two items to reduce complexity. Using [this document](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_special-characters_specialcharacters-SpecialCharacters.html) as a reference, I created the following function:

```
function SpecialCharactersSimple( editor ) {
    editor.plugins.get( 'SpecialCharacters' ).addItems( 'Simple', [
        { title: 'deg', character: '°' },
        { title: 'plusminus', character: '±' }
    ] );
}

 ClassicEditor
           .create( document.querySelector( '#SUMMARY' ), {
               extraPlugins: [SpecialCharactersSimple],
               toolbar: [//...]
           })
             .then(//...)
             .catch( error => {
                    console.error( error );
             } );
}
```

The problem is that when running ckeditor, the degree and plus minus signs are accompanied by Â and Â as seen in the following screenshot:
[incorrect special characters on ckeditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJSG0.png)

I found a workaround, but it is not ideal because it requires adding an EMOJI to the list of special characters, and that is an extra special character I do not want on the menu. The degree and plus minus signs are working with the following changes to the function below:

```
function SpecialCharactersSimple( editor ) {
    editor.plugins.get( 'SpecialCharacters' ).addItems( 'Simple', [
        { title: 'deg', character: '°' },
        { title: 'plusminus', character: '±' },
        { title: 'heart', character: '❤️' }
    ] );
}
```

I have tried other characters including a letter instead of an emoji, but by not adding an emoji to the addItem function, I receive the same error as outlined earlier in this post.
Here is a picture of the editor working as intended with the emoji in the menu:
[special characters with heart emoji](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U73Ul.png)

Any ideas as to why I am receiving this weird issue, and any suggestions on how to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like encoding in UTF-8 (two bytes for those special chars) is shown as Latin-1 or such. First ensure your editor works in UTF-8. Instead of `'±'` `'\u00B1'` should do too. Check your page encoding in the browser.